# Webpack cannot resolve file or dic

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack, jsx

MyAPP:

|--src

|--index.js

|--content.js

|--webpack.config.js

> index.js :

```
const React = require('react');
const ReactDom = require('react-dom');
const View = require('./content');

ReactDom.render(<View/>, document.body);
```

> content.js :

```
const React = require('react');
class view extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return <p> Content </p>
    }
}

module.exports = View;
```

> webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    entry: './src/*', 
    output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, '/build'),
    filename: '[name].bundle.js' 
    },
    resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
    },
   module: {
    loaders: [{

        test: /\.js|jsx$/,
        loader: ['jsx-loader?harmony'],
        exclude: /node_modules/
    }]
  },
  plugins: [commonsPlugin]
}
```

> Problems:
>
> webpack --display-error-details

Hash: c47fe037926d0dc83af7

Version: webpack 1.13.0

Time: 62ms`

```
Asset       Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
```

common.js  191 bytes       0  [emitted]  common.js

`ERROR in Entry module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' ./src/* in /Users/xx/WebstormProjects/jianwenji-react
resolve file`
  `/Users/xx/WebstormProjects/jianwenji-react/src/* doesn't exist`
  `/Users/xx/WebstormProjects/jianwenji-react/src/*.js doesn't exist`
  `/Users/xx/WebstormProjects/jianwenji-react/src/*.jsx doesn't exist`
resolve directory
  `/Users/xx/WebstormProjects/jianwenji-react/src/* doesn't exist (directory default file)`
  `/Users/xx/WebstormProjects/jianwenji-react/src/*/package.json doesn't exist (directory description file)`

> Why webpack can't find that files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case [`entry`](https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#entry) should refer to *file* not to *folder*,

```
module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js'
  // ....
}
```

**Note** - [`jsx-loader`](https://github.com/petehunt/jsx-loader) is deprecated, use [`babel-loader`](https://github.com/babel/babel-loader), [`babel-preset-react`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-preset-react) instead